# Windows - How to cleanup shared memory object left by processs terminated abnormally?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, shared-memory, resource-cleanup

I have encoutered with an issue where a process terminated abnormally and hence some shared resources (BaseNamedObjects) left unreleased by the process.

`CreateFileMapping` function returns `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` which indicates shared memory already exists.

After getting `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` by CreateFileMapping is returning a handle.
So I have following queries related to above scenario:

1. Can we perform cleanup using this returned handle?
2. Can we use the handle return by CreateFileMapping?
3. how to clean such shared memory object?

Comment: Your diagnosis seems incorrect. If all the processes that had opened handles to this object had terminated, then the system would have cleaned it up already. So there must still be an existing process that has an handle to the object.

Comment: if you not create object with `OBJ_PERMANENT` (for this need use native api and have special privilege - so can assume that not) - object will be auto destroyed when all handles for it closed (name will be removed) and reference released (reference can be from section mapping). not need do special cleanup. not all processes which have this handle terminated, if you got `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`

Comment: You are probably just using a generic name for your file mapping object, and someone else does, too. But how are we supposed to know without seeing a [mcve]?

Comment: Did you give the shared memory region a name?  If so, you should be able to search for it (and see what applications are using it) in [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

Answer (score 2):

The handle returned is entirely valid for you to continue to use, and you should close that handle when you have finished using it as usual. However, closing that handle won't release the memory or perform clean up: Your new call has increased the reference count to the shared resource, and closing will just decrease it back to its previous state.

It seems likely that there is some other process still using the shared memory, as the operating system should recover it after a process terminates fatally.

You might need some way to trigger that other process to self-destruct. One way is to reserve a small heartbeat counter in the region. If either process sees that the other has not updated its heartbeat count recently then it, too should abort, releasing the shared resource.

Possibly your other process has not actually died, but is in a fatal looping, or hopeless waiting, condition. To recover from this case, you might store all the process IDs in the shared region, and any new process with access to the shared region could then KILL all the old participants.